# MongoDB - how to get last item within a two level hierarchy

Tags: mongodb-query, pymongo

My goal is to get the last stock quote from a database for each of the ticker symbols in the list.

I found the $last function, but not sure how to apply it to a level of a hierarchy, i.e. the per ticker symbol.  (I just realized I only have need one level in the hierarchy now, but it would be nice to know how to do it for two als0. Per [this doc page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), the _id is supposed to be the group by expression, and I have set that to the ticker symbol.

(I'm using Python3 and PyMongo.)

This is the query I have now, but it is only returning one row.  I want it to return 4 rows, one for each ticker.

```
tickerList = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'NFLX']

docs = dbCollectionQuotes.aggregate([
            {'$match': {
                      '$and': [
                               {'timestampYear': 2020},
                               {'timestampMonth': 10},
                               {'timestampDay': 6},
                               {'timestampHour': 15},
                               {'ticker': {'$in':  tickerList }}
                      ]
            }},
            {'$sort': {
                    'ticker': 1,
                    'timestampIsoDateTime': 1
            }},
            {'$group': {
                    '_id': '$ticker',
                    'lastId': {'$last': '$_id'},
                    'minuteClose': {'$last': '$minuteClose'},
                    'todaysChangePerc': {'$last': '$todaysChangePerc'},
                    'timestampIsoDateTime': {'$last': '$timestampIsoDateTime'}
            }}
])
```

Comment: If I understand your question right, your query looks good. Are you sure that there are documents for more than 1 ticker that fulfil your $match requirements?

Comment: I'm checking now to see if it's a data issue, it might be.

Comment: The data seems to be there.  The query above is only returning for the first ticker in tickerList.

Comment: Can I not pass a list?  When I paste the same tickers into the Mongo query directly, I think it is working.

Comment: Your usage of $in is correct. I would try removing the timestamp fields, to see if there is any issues there. Compass has a very nice aggregate pipe builder that will output the results for each stage, its useful to narrow down where the issue is. https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass?tck=docs_compass

Comment: Add a sample document to your question please.

Comment: @BellyBuster It's a flat collection (no nesting) of all the fields in the questions, and maybe a hundred more.

Comment: Without it we'd all just be guessing.